# WCF INTERMITTENT no endpoint listening error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a web service in WCF/C# that calls an external vendor service for data thousands of times daily.  It works great most of the time, but lately, more and more we are getting concentrated periods of failure calling their service.  These outages last 10-15 minutes, during which 50-200 calls will fail, then everything just goes back to working fine again the rest of the day.  The vendor says the messages are not getting to them during these times.  The error we are getting is basically:

There was no endpoint listening at https://some.vendor.url/icantshare... that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Has anyone else experienced this kind of intermittent communication issue calling services from .NET?  If so, what was the cause?  There has been no code changes to our C# program for several months, and obviously no configuration changes are happening to change the URLs we're addressing in the middle of the day or anything like that.

Comment: How are you making the call to the external service? HttpClient can exhaust all TCP connections if you do not reuse the instance.

Comment: We are using a basicHttpBinding to the external service, if that is what you are asking.  How can I find out more about reusing connection instances?

Comment: OK, so it is not that.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has a similar problem I am documenting the solution.  There is no code issue in WCF, it was an infrastructure issue.   We changed the virtual NIC on our servers from an E1000(Intel) to a VMXNET3 (VMware) and suddenly we have no more errors.